# Is there a way to detect if user clicked a disabled button?

Tags: excel, vba, button, activex, isenabled

> Hey, I have an UserForm into which an user inputs varius profile
>   fields.
>
> Once it's filled in, there is verification - if anything goes astray,
>   the `CommandButton`, named  `save_button` is disabled

**What I want to achieve is**: If user clicks on the button, whilst it is in the disabled state, to display a `MsgBox` saying he needs to correct the incorrectly filled in field

---

For Demonstration purposes, I'm not gonna paste here the validation procedures, so let's just pretend that the `save_button.Enabled = False` is set from the getgo. Produces the same result.

```
save_button.Enabled = False ' already ran before, pretend this executes it
Private Sub save_button_Click()
    If save_button.Enabled = False Then
        MsgBox "Clicked disabled button"
    End If
End Sub
```

Issue is, once a CommandButton is set to `.Enabled = False` then it can no longer be officially clicked (hence it can't even trigger the `Click()`  procedure)

---

*My next thought was to use the `MouseUp` as a substitute. Issue is,
this triggers on any miniscule movement over the button and I don't want to bombard the user with `MsgBox`es*

---

> [image]

**Can you think of any alternatives, as to how to detect if user clicked the disabled button?**

Comment: Perhaps the answer is to validation each input as needed. If the form is set up correctly, a user should never be able to input incorrect data into any box. Then you can 1) rite a procedure that is called upon clicking the save button that checks if everything has been filled before continuing the code, or 2) not allow the save button to appear at all until everything has been filled it. This would require code on exit of each box that calls a function that only shows the save button when every necessary box has been chosen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a control is disabled, the click event bubbles up the tree. In your case, I guess the user form will get the click instead. If you put your save button inside a frame, that will get the click if the button is disabled. It is fairly easy to make the frame invisible, by setting

- Caption to ""
- BorderStyle to fmBorderStyleNone
- SpecialEffect to fmSpecialEffectFlat

And then size the frame so that is the same size as the button.
The code is easy:

```
Private Sub YourNewFrame_Click()
    MsgBox "Save button disabled!"
End Sub
```

Tip: If you draw the frame, cut your button and paste it inside your new frame, it will be placed properly. Properly, as in in the right part of the hierarchy. Visually, you will have to do manually.

Comment: hey actually one more issue - I only want the frame to be `Enabled` when the Button is disabfed. Which doesn't pose an issue. However.. if the frame is disabled, the button inside it also becomes disabled. Any way to circumvent this?

Comment: No need to touch the frame enabled property. Leave it enabled and let it enclose only the button and nothing more. Make it match the size of the button perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I want to offer another approach based on my comment to your question.

In the below gif, you will see that the 'Create Form' does not become enabled until all the necessary information is provided. You don't see it in the gif so much, but each entry that requires validation also has it behind the scenes in code.

[image]

The essential code behind that action is this:

```
Sub checkFields()

    Select Case True

        Case Len(Me.formTitleLine1) = 0, Len(Me.formPrefix) = 0, Len(Me.formNumber) = 0, Len(Me.formProduct) = 0, Len(Me.formEditionMonth) = 0, Len(Me.formEditionYear) = 0
            Me.createForm.Enabled = False
        Case Else
            Me.createForm.Enabled = True
    End Select

End Sub
```

And it's called on the `afterUpdate` event of each relevant box:

```
Private Sub formEditionYear_AfterUpdate()

    checkFields

End Sub
```

With one small change to the checkFields sub, you can only show the save button once everything has been filled in correctly. That change would be:

```
Me.createForm.Visible
```

instead of

```
Me.createForm.Enabled
```